# Slim route groups not working as expected

Tags: slim

In my code I am doing something very similar to the following (from the slim docs). My expected behaviour is that groups restrict the route scope to within that group e.g. /library/books is not the same as /books. However, I'm finding in my code that the group method is not restricting the route as expected and for example the route for /admin/tours is being called even when I go to /tours. Is there something I am missing? The docs  for group on the homepage (www.slimframework.com) of the slim website are different from the documentation website (http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/groups/).

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// API group
$app->group('/api', function () use ($app) {

    // Library group
    $app->group('/library', function () use ($app) {

        // Get book with ID
        $app->get('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

        // Update book with ID
        $app->put('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

        // Delete book with ID
        $app->delete('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

    });

});
```

Further example

```
    $app->group( '/admin', function () use ( $app , $twig) {

        $app->get('/tours', function() use ($app){

            print_r('do tours admin');
        });


});

        $app->get('/tours', function() use ($app){

                print_r('do tours');
            });
```

my behaviour is that /tours is still routing to /admin/tours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bit of a simple solution but ordering the registering of the /tours route before the  /admin/tours route sorted it.